# Unable to change Tabs backgraound color

Tags: react-native

Using native base and `style={{backgroundColor:"red"}}` doesn't work in tab unable to change background color
how to change the tab background color?

```js
<Tabs style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }} renderTabBar={() => <ScrollableTab />}>
  <Tab heading="Tab1">
    <Tab1 />
  </Tab>
  <Tab heading="Tab2">
    <Tab2 />
  </Tab>
  <Tab heading="Tab3">
    <Tab3 />
  </Tab>
  <Tab heading="Tab4">
    <Tab4 />
  </Tab>
  <Tab heading="Tab5">
    <Tab5 />
  </Tab>
</Tabs>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change `Tab` background color, I used `heading` attribute by passing component instead of plain text.

Have a look at the following sample

```
...
import { ... Tabs, Tab, TabHeading } from 'native-base';
...
render() {
  return (
    ...
    <Tabs>
     <Tab 
       heading={
          <TabHeading style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
            <Text>Tab 1</Text>
          </TabHeading>
       }
     >
       ...
     </Tab>
     <Tab 
       heading={
          <TabHeading style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
            <Text>Tab 2</Text>
          </TabHeading>
       }
     >
       ...
     </Tab>
    </Tabs>
  );
}
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: The only thing that works for me. However, Cannot set the color to 'transparent'. Can you?

Comment: Also, is there any way to set text color when the tab is not selected. The only thing I can do is to set the tab's text color, and it is bold when selected, regular when not selected

Comment: Hi @Yossi, not so sure about `transparency`, actually I don't use `native-base` on regular basis. I need to look at the uses!!!

Answer (score 1):

just give the style to the `<Tab style={{  backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}>` component, this works fine for me